# Java and ExtentReport : how to add New line in JSON format

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

I have several fields that i parse from `HTML` page and add into my `report`:

```
extentTest.log(Status.INFO, String.format(
                "Add new record into database (%s)",
                "{\n" +
                        "   Name = name, \n".replace("name", name) +
                        "   Description = description, \n".replace("description", description) +
                        "   Language = language, \n".replace("language", language) +
                        "   Time = time, \n".replace("time", time) +
                        "}"));
```

So instead of see this in my HTML report with this kind of format:

```
Document{{
   Name = 5967745223993a32646baab8, 
   Description = "bla bla, 
   Language = en,
   Time = "2534
}}
```

is see in like this (without new lines):

> Document{{ Name = 5967745223993a32646baab8, Description = MongoDB,
>   Language = en,
>              Time = "2534 }}

Any suggestions ?

Comment: fyi, version 4 accepts your Json and automatically formats it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of "\n" you need to use `<br />` tag for Extent report new line,

```
extentTest.log(Status.INFO, String.format(
                "Add new record into database (%s)","{<br />" +
                        "   Name = name, <br />".replace("name", name) +
                        "   Description = description, <br />".replace("description", description) +
                        "   Language = language, <br />".replace("language", language) +
                        "   Time = time, <br />".replace("time", time) +
                        "}"));
```

Comment: BTW if i want to change all its color to green ?

Comment: extentTest.info(MarkupHelper.createLabel("Your String", ExtentColor.GREEN));

Comment: This is the Background, and change for foreground ?

Comment: This is the only provision given by ExtentReport, Else you have write your own CSS in config.xml https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/blob/master/extent-config.xml

Comment: Use class="text-green" for green color text.